# Fill polygon with SVG image pattern

Tags: polygon, openlayers, style, fill

I want to fill my polygons in openlayers 3 to make them look like this:
[image]

In QGIS I can provide a svg image to create this kind of pattern. How can this be achieved in openlayers 3?

#### Background / Research so far

I intensively read through the API documentation and found out that the `ol.style.Fill` class accepts an `ol.ColorLike` object.
A `ol.ColorLike` Object again accepts a `CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle`, which can be an image pattern or a gradient. So I guess it should be technically possible to tweak the openlayers API to achieve a patterned polygon fill.

See these links for further information:

1. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Fill.html
2. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.colorlike.html
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern

#### Putting the Pieces together

This is my code so far and here begins the trouble. I can't find a way to get a working instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. It always returns with `undefined`.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-unselectable') // filter <canvas>
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
var colorLike;

img.onload = function() {
      var pattern = CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
      CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle = pattern;
      colorLike = CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle
}  

var style = new ol.style.Style({

      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
           color: colorLike // ol.ColorLike object
      })
  })
```

To see the full code visit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmarquar/toh7tw7h/5/)

**Is there a way to access the polygon drawing canvas prior initializing it? Or how can I create a correct CanvasRenderingContext2D instance here?**

Answer (score 1):

ok, sometimes you don't realize that you're almost at the finish line...following [SE Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835929/in-openlayers-3-how-to-fill-the-polygon-with-a-picture-from-a-url) pointed me into the right direction and after adding some lines of code it now works :)

**Working Example:**

```
var geojsonObject = 'someGeoJSON' 
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
   features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
  });

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: source
});

var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
img.onload = function() {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: pattern
    })
  }));
};
```

Full working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmarquar/toh7tw7h/14/)

Comment: I think this is not a very clever thing to do. Imagine a huge amount of polygons and a style function. You must create one style for every polygon to use its attributes to styling (a size based color for example)... You'll have an `img` overload even you decide to create tha canvas outside the feature styling "loop"...